# Send a large number of emails daily with java or php

Tags: mail-server, bulk-email

I am going to buy my own dedicated server and I'll need to send over 10,000,00 emails daily as per my client's requirement. Could you please suggest me any kind of robust email service. Whether it is

1. A Top Class Email Marking Service
2. An Email Server Built In Any Language must run on centos or ubuntu linux system
3. An Email Library in php that can handle such a large number of emails
4. Or any other open source mail server that should install on linux and run without interruption.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to send 1 million emails a day for free ? and without existing knowledge of high volume mailing? Consider some paid services. Email is daunting :)

Comment: Actually I'm not willing to do this. This is my client's requirement and I don't know weather he is kidding with me or something else

Comment: I also don't consider him as sending such a large number of email but could you please suggest me something.

Comment: You might want to tell your client you need paid solutions for those. I'm not saying one cant do it themselves writing their own code but if neither are you willing nor do you have any experience of that number of mails, just don't. It will waste all your time with no results.

Comment: Can you suggest any paid service that is the best??

Comment: Search Google for `Bulk MTA`